# Docker image build with PHP zip extension shows "bundled libzip is deprecated" warning

Tags: php, docker, php-extension, libzip

I have a `Dockerfile` with a build command like this:

```
#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

I get this warning from build output:

> WARNING: Use of bundled libzip is deprecated and will be removed.
>   configure: WARNING: Some features such as encryption and bzip2 are not available.
>   configure: WARNING: Use system library and --with-libzip is
>   recommended.

What is the correct way to install the zip extension without these warnings?

My complete Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update

#install some basic tools
RUN apt-get install -y \
        git \
        tree \
        vim \
        wget \
        subversion

#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

#setup composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer


WORKDIR /var/www/
```

Comment: try `apt-get install php7.0-zip`

Comment: @Vladimir its docker I think they suggest  to use `docker-php-ext-install` https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Answer (score 256, accepted):

It [looks like](https://externals.io/message/98731) PHP no longer bundles [libzip](https://libzip.org/). You need to [install it](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/61). You install `zlib1g-dev`, but instead install `libzip-dev`. This installs `zlib1g-dev` as a dependency and allows the `configure` script to detect that `libzip` is installed.

For PHP < 7.3, you then need to

```
docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip
```

before performing the installation with

```
docker-php-ext-install zip
```

as the last warning indicates.

In short: change the relevant part of your Dockerfile to

**For PHP < 7.3**

```
#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

**For PHP >= 7.3**

```
#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

I have verified that this builds as expected.

---

In case you are not using the Docker [PHP base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), things may be much easier. For example, for Alpine the following Dockerfile will get you PHP 7 with the zip extension installed.

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add php7 php7-zip composer
```

Comment: thanks, it solved an issue I had upgrading from 7.1

Comment: Thank you! It is clear. When you are moving from 7.3 to 7.4, you have to remove `docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip`

Comment: i'm using php:8.1-apache and it seems like the `zlib1g-dev` package is needed as well.

Answer (score 22):

In case you are using 7.4 this worked for me:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache zip libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Comment: This worked for me using 7.4.

Comment: fyi php:7.4-fpm-alpine has critical security issues https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/7.4.0-fpm-alpine/images/sha256-35565c5edd4dd676a7ea7d7b566eab08b2ee6474263f6cd384d4d29d4590a199

Answer (score 11):

Apparently the zip extension needs the `libzip-dev` package at runtime (not just build time). I originally added the `apk add libzip-dev` to a virtual package I installed along with `gcc make postgresql-dev` which I later removed to keep the image small.

This works:

```
RUN apk add openjdk11-jre-headless libzip-dev \ # libzip-dev not part of virtual package
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual \
     .build-deps autoconf g++ make postgresql-dev  \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql bcmath \
  && pecl install redis-5.3.1 \
  && pecl install xdebug-beta \
  && docker-php-ext-enable redis opcache xdebug \
  && apk add libpq ca-certificates curl \
  && apk del .build-deps  \
  && rm -rf /tmp/* \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

This does *not* work:

```
RUN apk add openjdk11-jre-headless \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual \
     .build-deps autoconf g++ make postgresql-dev libzip-dev \ # libzip-dev part of virtual package
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql bcmath \
  && pecl install redis-5.3.1 \
  && pecl install xdebug-beta \
  && docker-php-ext-enable redis opcache xdebug \
  && apk add libpq ca-certificates curl \
  && apk del .build-deps  \
  && rm -rf /tmp/* \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: I'm using php7.4-fpm-alpine and this is the only thing that worked for me. Nice catch!

Comment: installing `libzip` alongside `libzip-dev` then uninstalling `libzip-dev` would also work

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee my conclusion when I tested this last year was that uninstalling libzip-dev after building lipzip broke the library

Comment: I can confirm, `libzip-dev` is required at runtime.

Answer (score 9):

I built a PHP container on Docker using `php:7.2-fpm-alpine`

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk add --no-cache zip libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Comment: You might want to say why that's different/better than OP's recipe, and also why you're installing zip as an extra docker-php-ext-install (which creates an extra layer).

Comment: This example helped me a lot, as I'm using alpine for my container too. Thanks! @GregBell I do agree running multiple RUN commands seems less efficient.

Answer (score 7):

In order to build a php/apache container you just have to first install *libzip-dev* library. At least using the docker image php:7.3-apache

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
MAINTAINER XXX

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I built a PHP dockerfile using php:7.4-fpm-alpine

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
    
    # Apk install
    RUN apk --no-cache update && apk --no-cache add bash git
    RUN apk add --no-cache zip libzip-dev

    RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
    RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
    
    # Install composer
    RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && php composer-setup.php && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    
    # Symfony CLI
    RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
    
    WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

# Install persistent dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --update \
    bash \
    imagemagick \
    ghostscript \
    zip \
    unzip \
    nano \
    libzip-dev \
    libgomp


# Install the PHP extensions
RUN set -ex; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
        freetype-dev \
        icu-dev \
        imagemagick-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    ; \
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip
```